# Android Java filepicker choose application to pick file

Tags: java, android, upload, filepicker

Say i want to upload a picture or a text document 
when i click on the button to chose the file
how do i make it so that it shows a bunch a popup of applications i can chose from to look at files and select on for the upload as in this picture[image]

i currently have this

```
   public void sendFile(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

but this goes straight to documents and doesn't let me choose an application like gallery or MEGA

any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: because you may already set `xxx` application as default

Answer (score 2):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidPick_a_File extends Activity {

 TextView textFile;

 private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Button buttonPick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonpick);
       textFile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textfile);

       buttonPick.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             intent.setType("file/*");
       startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

   }});
   }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch(requestCode){
  case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
   if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
    String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
    textFile.setText(FilePath);
   }
   break;

  }
 }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >

<Button
   android:id="@+id/buttonpick"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="- PICK a file -"
   />
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/textfile"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Aha Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT gives me way more options nice
Still how would i get the popup that is in the image i posted

Comment: Yes it will list all the installed app which support this action.

Comment: This is not how it should be done. Check the answer below. We are not in android 2.3 anymore. The experience has to be unified and is what the user expects

Comment: @Akshay Chopde
Great simplicity by author. Thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that file selection has to be done via the Android system's File Picker. Other apps like drive and Dropbox will be listen on the navigation drawer on the left. Mega should have code inside it so that it's content is visible in the Android system's File Picker. That is how it is supposed to be. Android made the file picking process unified.

It's not the case while sharing a file though. In that case you would get option to choose from like the screenshot you posted

[image]